# PowerShell not working on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: powershell

I have accidently installed .Net 4.5 on my Windows Server 2008 R2 for PowerShell 5.1, but now I have reverted to .Net 4.0 version and now the PowerShell is not working. It gives below error.

> Windows PowerShell terminated with the following error: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)'

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: please help. i need it urgently

Comment: have you installed Windows Management Framework 4?

Comment: no i just installed .net 4.0

Comment: i need .net 4.0 and a supported powershell. .net framework is there but powershell gui is not opening

Comment: tried installing Windows Management Framework 4.0 and it says the update is already installed Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg

Comment: This is not a programming issue. Please post questions like this on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the same issue you have: https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-method-not-found-system-threading-tasks-task-system-threading-tasks-task-runsystem-action/

If that does not work for you, you can always reinstall Powershell 3.0. Download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

You can also install a higher version if you would like. It would do no harm. Reinstall will require a reboot as they come in the form of KBs.

Comment: uninstalled WMF updates for 5.1 and 5.0 and powershell is working now. hope it has nothing to do with .net and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download Windows Management Framework 3.0 or install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 to correct your issue.

Windows Management Framework 3.0 - [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 - [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851)

or you can get

Windows Management Framework 4.0 - [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855)

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 - [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

Comment: I will clear my requirement. I have .Net 4.0 and wmf 4 already. Power shell  is also there but it's not opening and throwing the error mentioned already. What should I do now ?

Comment: because you need wmf 4.0 and .Net 4.5 or wmf 3.0 and .Net 4.0... you cant do .Net 4.0 and and wmf 4. `WMF 4.0 requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.`

Comment: right now all you need to do is install `Windows Management Framework 3.0` or install `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5`

Comment: installed .net 4.0 using wic_x64_enu.exe . how do i confirm which WMF i am using? when i tried to install WMF 4.0 it says update already installed in your PC

Comment: tried doing WMF 3.0 with Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu but it says the update is not applicable for this computer

Comment: try uninstalling wmf 4 and then install it `Control Panel/Programs/Uninstall a program/View installed updates`... anything past coding you will need to escalate this issue to the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) site.

Comment: i saw WMF 5.1 in installed updates and i uninstalled it. getting below error on starting powershell Windows PowerShell terminated with the following error:
 The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Tracing.PSEtwLog' threw an exception.